# Role of secondary antenna for a UHF RFID tag

Tags: antenna, rfid, induction

I am trying to understand the role of a secondary antenna that I have seen in some UHF RFID tags. I believe it's to increase the read range of the tag.

The module seems to have an internal antenna soldered to the IC. Additionally, there is a single wire laid around the module, similar to NFC/HF tags, but without any physical connection to the module.

[image: A laundry tag with this construction]

[Tech specs of this tag](https://www.spo-tag.com/product/5815-textile-laundry-tag.html)

This type of setup is typical for NFC or HF tags based on inductive coupling. I have a little background in RFID, but this is the first time I have come across an antenna used in this manner. I am a bit confused about the role of this antenna. It would be very helpful if you could clarify the following:

- How is this antenna combining the inductive and back-scatter/radiative coupling?
- Also  with regards to inductive coupling, it's not actually a coil, rather a meander shaped wire. Would it still behave as a coil?
- I suppose it's a monopole antenna, but how can I calculate the required length for tuning at a specific frequency?

Comment: Please provide a data sheet link to the tag.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't find any datasheet for it and there is no manufacturer's name that can be searched on the internet

Comment: On what basis would you expect anyone reading your question to naturally recognize the make and model from your description and, from that recognition, realize what the various bits of the tag do? Would it be reasonable to expect this do you think?

Comment: That's a fair remark. However I am curious about understanding the underlying principles or mechanisms and not the specific model. Like the unusual combination of the inductive and radiative coupling phenomenon which seems very unique to me. So I thought more experienced and knowledgeable people might already have seen such tags and can clarify the mechanisms at play here.

Comment: Don't know that UHF tag have secondary antenna https://www.huayuansh.com/product/ultra-thin-washable-rfid-tag-for-apparel-management/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIk5iI7dOF_QIVSI1oCR2yrgBiEAAYASAAEgKcc_D_BwE  https://www.dipolerfid.fr/produits/tags-rfid/Tag-RFID-UHF

Comment: Or active tags https://www.rfidinc.com/uhf-433-mhz-active-rfid-tags

Comment: @Andyaka I have found one such tag on the web and have updated my post with the picture and tech specs

Comment: @Antonio51 it's a passive tag actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand RFID, it helps to let go of some traditional assumptions about antennas. The tag and reader may follow antenna and far-field radiation principles at long ranges, but at close range they are sometimes better analyzed as inductively-coupled resonant circuits.

From your description it sounds like you're puzzled by a loop antenna with no electrical connections to the circuit. A closed conductive loop can be resonant when its circumference is 1 wavelength; on dielectric it would be somewhat smaller. If the loop conductor meanders, that increases the effective length so the loop diameter can be smaller. (It's not a monopole as you were assuming.)

However, now that a picture has been added it's apparent that the antenna is actually a dipole. The ends are serpentined and there is a 1-turn loading coil in each arm; together these shorten the overall physical length at which the antenna is resonant.

The dipole feed arrangement may seem unusual: a 1-turn coil at the dipole midpoint, inductively coupled to the IC, which probably has a multi-turn coil. This accomplishes two things: 1) it avoids having to electrically bond feed conductors from the IC to the antenna element (which is probably a thin foil) and 2) it allows for an impedance transformation -- probably a step-up in impedance and voltage in the receiving mode, as needed to power up the RFID IC. This transformer effect operates in reverse to match the output impedance of the tag to the loop when transmitting / scattering signal back to the reader.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying things up. In the meantime, I have found on web one such tag that is used for laundry applications. I have updated my original post with the picture and the link to the datasheet.

Comment: Referring to the picture of the tag, Initially I didn't consider it as a closed loop (with both ends connected end to end). So in this case I assume the small loop formed by the antenna around the chip is the closed conducting loop. Am I interpreting it correctly? In fact there are three loops in total, so do the additional loops increase the induced current?

Comment: @Zaffresky  The picture clarifies things. The antenna is a dipole, not a loop. The small loop around the RFID module is NOT closed (i.e. not shorted) and neither are the other two loops. What I said about inductive coupling between the RFID module and antenna still stands.

Comment: @Zaffresky I've edited my answer to better explain the RFID tag in the photo.